# Timestamps in different formats in the same variable

Tags: r, data.table, zoo, lubridate

I have a timestamp in three different formats in the same variable. How do I convert all the variables into a same format?

```
 ts<- c("2012-01-11T01:18:29Z",  "2012/03/17 19:29:05 -0700", "2012-09-24T21:07:12-07:00")
```

I want to have output like this. Any suggestions?

```
ts<- c("2012-01-11T01:18:29Z", "2012-03-17T19:29:05Z","2012-09-24T21:07:12Z")
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to deal with different time zones potentially or are you happy to assume that they're all in the same timezone? Have a look at `anytime::anytime()` and `lubridate::ymd_hms()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `lubridate` for this:

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms(ts)
[1] "2012-01-11 01:18:29 UTC" "2012-03-18 02:29:05 UTC"
[3] "2012-09-25 04:07:12 UTC"
```

However, I think it is interpreting the -0700 as an offset from UTC or Zulu (Z) time. Are you sure they are in the same timezone?

Comment: thanks! yeah they are in different time zone, I don't know how I would normalize it to make it uniform, please suggest

Comment: Actually in the code above lubridate does it for you, that's why the hours and days in the output are different from the original input.

Comment: oh, kool! awesome!